# llc has no debug or -view-dag-combine1-dags option

Tags: llvm, llc

I have `llc` program installed on my computer via package manager (of course I have LLVM installed, 6.0.0 version). Also, I have it built from sources. What I want is to view DAGs, generated by llvm. But, unfortunately, I don't have any of options like `-debug`, `-view-dag-combine1-dags` and etc on both versions of `llc`. This drives me crazy since it is written everywhere, that this flags should help me, but it is not mentioned what to do if I don't have them. In help and man, there are no such options. I have graphviz, dot and gv installed, it should not be the problem.

Version of compiled `llc`.

```
./llc -version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
LLVM version 7.0.0svn
Optimized build.
Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Host CPU: broadwell

Registered Targets:
   and targets...
```

I've built it with RelWithDebugInfo flag, maybe I should've built it with Debug flag? Or is there any flag in cmake, that I should enable? I believe that I've googled enough and I couldn't find any information.

Comment: you first wrote version is 6.0.0 then 7.0.0 ... which one is it? :]]

Answer (score 5):

Executing `llc --help-hidden | grep view-dag` using my debug build results in:

> -filter-view-dags=                                     -
>   Only display the basic block whose name matches this for all
>   view-*-dags options
>   -view-dag-combine-lt-dags                                      - Pop up a window to show dags before the post legalize types dag combine
>   pass
>   -view-dag-combine1-dags                                        - Pop up a window to show dags before the first dag combine pass
>   -view-dag-combine2-dags                                        - Pop up a window to show dags before the second dag combine pass

If you look into `llvm/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/SelectionDAGISel.cpp`, that command-line option is between `#ifndef NDEBUG` preprocessor statements, so those options are only exposed when you have a debug build.

Changing the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Debug` and recompiling should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although I can't check, if it is a solutions, since I can't build llvm in debug, I just don't have enough memory:)

Comment: You can also use a release+asserts build, which is much smaller: http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#viewing-graphs-while-debugging-code

Comment: @ayke That must be a relic from the Make part of build system. The [CMake doc](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) says "Enables code assertions. Defaults to ON **if and only if** CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is Debug." for the `LLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS`  variable

Comment: I believe it worked the last time I checked, with a release+assert build. Maybe `LLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS` does not imply `!NDEBUG`.

Answer (score 0):

I did it and it works.

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
```

You can check: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/docs/CMake.rst#id5

and if you want to check DAGs then maybe it helps you.

here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095047/12365658