# Dot file not genearting for -view-isel-dags option

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, graphviz, dot, llc

While trying to see the `SelectionDag` nodes generated during the instruction selection phase using LLVM (built from sources with debug mode enabled), I am using the below command which is not creating Graphviz DOT file.

```
llc -view-isel-dags sum.bc
```

Instead it is creating `sum.s` file. Is there something I'm missing here?

*sum.c*

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

*sum.bc*

```
$ clang -emit-llvm sum.c -c -o sum.bc
```

*LLVM information*

```
$ llc -help-hidden | grep 'view-isel' -view-isel-dags - Pop up a window to show isel dags as they are selected

$ llvm-config --build-mode
Debug
```

Comment: Usually the `-view` options create a DOT file in `/tmp` and directly open it in a GraphViz viewer. So, you can find the `.dot` file under `/tmp`. Looking at `SelectionDAGISel.cpp` it does not offer an option for just creating a `.dot` file. The `.s` is a product of the `llc` commands, since it lowers the IR to a specific assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Ain't  find the `.dot` file under `/tmp`.

Comment: When issuing that command, I'm getting `Writing '/tmp/dag.compute_rhs-22fa16.dot'...  done.` output lines. Don't you get anything similar?

Comment: No, nothing is printing to the terminal.

Comment: does `llc -help-hidden | grep 'view-isel'` return anything? Also, what does `llvm-config --build-mode` print? Can you please amend your question with this info, to avoid long discussion in the comments?

Comment: Thanks, updated the question.

Comment: I can't think of anything else that might affect this, apart from the actual `sum.bc` file. What is the initial source and how do you obtain the bitcode file? Again, amend the question please. Thanks

Comment: Please repeat the steps, but in order to emit the bitcode use this command instead: `clang -O1 -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes  -emit-llvm sum.c -c -o sum.bc`

Comment: Thank you, updated answer. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I suspect that the problem was that the `sum` function had the `optnone` attribute (you can search for that in the `.ll` file). This option disables any optimizations taking place over that function. The previous command I posted outputs IR without that option. After that, I was able to get the graph without any other changes.

Comment: I guess you are right. But the option how does disable llvm passes enable optimization passes. Command is bit confusing. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: That option does not annotate the function with the `optnone` attribute. After that you can use `opt` to run `-O2` or any optimization and also get the `fast-isel` DAGs in graphviz.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess the problem is with fast instruction selection which is enabled by default.

`$ llc -debug sum.ll`

Skipping pass 'X86 DAG->DAG Instruction Selection' on function sum

Changing optimization level for Function sum
Before: -O2 ; After: -O0

FastISel is enabled

Disabling fastIsel resolved this problem.

`$ llc -fast-isel=false -view-dag-combine1-dags sum.ll`